# build C Project in Vis Studio 2022 - Error:C1189 - Error in C++ Standard Library usage

Tags: c, compilation

I am trying to create **c** project in visual studio 2022.
I have installed:
Desktop development with C from windows installer
Window 10 SDK 10.0.19041.0
I have windoes 10 as operating system.
I have added to the path the installed minGW
I have updated the compile as C code (/Tc)
Added the SDK to the additional include directories

Any idea what should I do to be able to compile C Code?
thanks

I tried to configured the env and would like to run c code

Comment: What is the actual error? What is the code that demonstrates the error? Are you actually using Visual Studio 2022 or are you using Visual Studio Code? The former would normally not have anything to do with MinGW.

Comment: @RetiredNinja it is `#error` directive in the source code or header files.

Comment: #include <iostream>

int main()
{
    printf("hrllo");
 
} 

from a file with extension .c

Comment: the error:
// This does not use `_EMIT_STL_ERROR`, as it needs to be checked before we include anything else.
// However, `_EMIT_STL_ERROR` has a dependency on `_CRT_STRINGIZE`, defined in `<vcruntime.h>`.
// Here, we employ the same technique as `_CRT_STRINGIZE` in order to avoid needing to update the line number.
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define _STL_STRINGIZE_(S) #S
#define _STL_STRINGIZE(S)  _STL_STRINGIZE_(S)
#pragma message(__FILE__ "(" _STL_STRINGIZE(__LINE__) "): STL1003: Unexpected compiler, expected C++ compiler.")
#error Error in C++ Standard Library usage
#endif // __cplusplus

Comment: I am using visual studio 2022 community eddition

Comment: Thank you, after understandig that the error is not generic, read the comment above, my issue was including <iostream> which is c++ changes it to #include <stdio.h>.

Answer (score 1):

`Error C1189` is an error generated by the `#error` directive.

The full error message will include the file name & the line. Check in the source code why the preprocessor has reached this directive.

Example:

```
#undef _WIN32
#if !defined(_WIN32)
#error _WIN32 must be defined   // C1189
#endif
```

Comment: the error:
// This does not use `_EMIT_STL_ERROR`, as it needs to be checked before we include anything else.
// However, `_EMIT_STL_ERROR` has a dependency on `_CRT_STRINGIZE`, defined in `<vcruntime.h>`.
// Here, we employ the same technique as `_CRT_STRINGIZE` in order to avoid needing to update the line number.
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define _STL_STRINGIZE_(S) #S
#define _STL_STRINGIZE(S)  _STL_STRINGIZE_(S)
#pragma message(__FILE__ "(" _STL_STRINGIZE(__LINE__) "): STL1003: Unexpected compiler, expected C++ compiler.")
#error Error in C++ Standard Library usage
#endif // __cplusplus

Comment: Thank you, after understandig that the error is not generic, read the comment above, my issue was including <iostream> which is c++ changes it to #include <stdio.h>.